# can't add property with jquery with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox that has a `.keyup()` function attached to it, like this:

```
$("#textbox").keyup(function(){
    var amount = $("#textbox").val().length;
    var max = 60;
    $("#charsLeft").text(max - amount);

    if(amount == 60){
      $("#textbox").prop('disabled');
}
});
```

The number is read out below the textbox, like I want it to, but the textbox doesn't become disabled when the number hits the max, it just keeps going negative. The textbox should become disabled when the number hits 0. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `$("#textbox").prop('disabled');` is the getter version. If you want to set it, use: `$("#textbox").prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. Put that in an answer, I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$("#textbox").prop('disabled', true);`. You have to specify the value you'd like to set.